# Does Named Entity Recognition only work on nouns?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am considering training spaCy to recognize a custom named entity, but I am curious if this really only works for nouns or if it would equally work well with POS such as adjectives?

For example, I want to train on words like **depressed**, **anxious**, **paranoid**, etc.  I'm trying to curate a list of adjectives that are considered *clinically relevant*, separating them from other irrelevant adjectives like **happy**, **sad**, **unwell**.

Is NER the right approach here, would it make more sense to just manually maintain a list of clinical adjectives and use a custom extension (e.g. ent._.clinical_adj) to mark them?

Answer (score 0):

NER is typically used mainly on nouns. It's not that sensitive to part of speech type, but picking up just adjectives would be an unusual use.

Since it sounds like you do have a specific, finite list of words you're interested in, it probably makes sense for you to just use that word list and an extension to mark them.

You might also want to look at the [DependencyMatcher](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#dependencymatcher). If there are some nouns you are interested in, you can use the DependencyMatcher to get all adjectives that modify them, for example.